# How can I search for all items which references match an input that can be multiple reference separated by a comma in excel?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, pattern-matching

I am trying to write an excel formula that can output in a single cell all items from a table that matches the target reference. As an example, I have made a table with two columns that looks like the following :

```
ITEM               NUMBER

A1                 01
A2                 01
A3                 02
A4                 03
A4                 04
A5                 04
A6                 01
A7                 05
A8                 06
A9                 02
A10                07
```

Numbers can be attributed to different items simultaneously and items can have more than one number attributed to them.

In this table , I aim to retrieve all items that are related to a number I set as an input.
For example, 01 as an input would give me A1,A2,A6.

This input can also be multiple numbers separated by a comma, and an input set as "02,05" would return all items related to these two numbers : "A3,A7,A9".

i have achieved this in Google Sheets with the following formula :

```
=JOIN(","; UNIQUE(FILTER(A:A; ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXMATCH(","&B:B&","; ",("&SUBSTITUE(C2; ","; "|")&"),")))))
```

Where :

- column A corresponds to the Item List
- column B corresponds to the component List
- Cell C2 is where I write my input

This formula works perfectly but I need to have the equivalent on excel for other purposes, and I didn't manage to "convert" this formula without the same functions as in Google Sheets.

There are some ways I found on the net that can output all matching items for a given component but they don't implement the possibility of having multiple inputs separated by a comma.

Would anyone have any idea of how I can do it ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thank you very much for all of your replies, I tested all of the methods you proposed and they work like a charm !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option:

[image]

Formula in `E2`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",,REPT(A2:A12,ISNUMBER(FIND(B2:B12,D2))))
```

Or, more dynamic, but fast:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",,REPT(TOCOL(A:A,1),ISNUMBER(FIND(TOCOL(B:B,1),D2))))
```

And, for `UNIQUE()` values:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",,UNIQUE(REPT(TOCOL(A:A,1),ISNUMBER(FIND(TOCOL(B:B,1),D2)))))
```

This should work since you have formatted each number to the '##' format.

Comment: Thank you very much, the second one does work just fine !

Comment: I noticed that if you have an item that matches different numbers, and you make a search for these numbers, the item would be written once for each number search : for example, writing 03,04 as an input would output "A4,A4,A5". Is there a way to remove the doubles ?

Comment: @PanduPpu use `UNIQUE()` Function.

Answer (score 1):

Another:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",,FILTER(A2:A12,1-ISNA(XMATCH(B2:B12,TEXTSPLIT(D2,",")))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another alternative:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `E2`

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,REPT(A2:A12,TEXTSPLIT(D2,",")=B2:B12))
```

---

Edit: For UNIQUE Values:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,UNIQUE(TOCOL(REPT(A2:A12,TEXTSPLIT(D4,",")=B2:B12))))
```

---

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `E2`

```
=ARRAYTOTEXT(FILTER(A2:A12,ISNUMBER(XMATCH(B2:B12,TEXTSPLIT(D2,,",")))))
```

---

Or,

[image]

---

```
=LET(
       a,N(TEXTSPLIT(D2,",")=B2:B12)*ROW(B1:B11),
       b,TOCOL(IF(a=0,NA(),a),3),
       TEXTJOIN(", ",,INDEX(A2:A12,b)))
```

---

Comment: `=TEXTJOIN(", ",,REPT(A2:A12,TEXTSPLIT(D2,",")=B2:B12))` is worth a vote!

Comment:  its all because of you Sir 

Comment: Thank you, these are a lot of ways to do it indeed !